# Hosting a simple node API

Tags: node.js, api, heroku, server, hosting

If I were to host a simple Node API (or any API for that matter), such that on requesting the hosted URI path, it must return an object to the client.

For Example:
If a client makes a request to the API, the API must return the IP address along with the request type.
I'm particularly worried about the hosting part, not the implementation of the API itself as I'm already well aware of it.

Any suggestion or resource links are appreciated.

PS: Not very familiar with hosting server or Devops.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I understood your question propery.

> PS: Not very familiar with hosting server or Devops.

You should definitely be familiar with system administration on the respective operating system and environment. Which you haven't mentioned.

I almost downvoted your post, because it's not even a real question. I'd recommend to consult your favourite search engine first.

Answer (score 0):

Try heroku they have nice documentation and free hosting

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction